# from android 4.3, toast showing make top activity onPause()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toast

My application make toast showing and then my top acitivity goes to onPause().

However, I do NOT wanna make top acitivity goes to onPause when "my own" toast showing()

Or, maybe, how can I can tell the difference between toast showing and other activity showing (they both leads to my top activity goes go onPause() ) ?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior from the description alone. Are you sure it's the Toast causing it? Do you have a code example?

Comment: u mean Toast won't lead ur top activity into onPause() ?